# Strange chart size problem in Eclipse BIRT

Tags: reporting, birt

I have a grid containing a bar chart that spans the whole width of the page. SVG output doesn´t seem to work, but the PNG image gets rendered and layed out correctly in the Eclipse (3.6.2) preview and the BIRT web viewer (Apache Tomcat 6, IE 8 and Firefox 3.6) on Windows Vista (screen resolution 1920x1080).

If I deploy the same report to a Windows XP based Tomcat 6 installation (screen size 1024x768), the chart gets rendered at roughly a third of its original width when viewed in a web browser (same versions as above) on localhost. The rest of the report looks ok. Nothing is gained by placing the chart outside of the grid or changing the system´s screen resolution and font size settings.

It looks like the new image size happens to be exactly (!) the default size of chart elements as they were originally inserted from the BIRT designer palette.

Am I missing something? Has anyone ever come across the same problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with BIRT WebViewer 2.6.1. Try version 2.6.2. That solve my case.